# Does the bonus from a shield have any affect in lockdown?

Tags: spiral-knights

Specifically, I'm interested in the damage bonus from the Bristling Buckler line.  Since shields aren't *used* in lockdown, do you get the bonus if you equip it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't get the bonus because if you open your player window while playing Lockdown, you will see that the only shield you have *equipped* is the shield that you receive in-game, whether it be the *striker booster*, the *guardian shield*, or the *recon* stealth marker (or whatever it's called). However, you **do** get bonuses from these shields such as the **sword attack speed increase** from the *striker booster* shield.